# ajax returning 404 but showing json?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

https://ecuhelsinki.futurez.fi/suoritusluvut/

This page is returning an error on the console that the file https://ecuhelsinki.futurez.fi/wp-content/plugins/wp-plg-ct-vehicle-stats_1.0.5/includes/ctvc_ajax.php?r&ct_method=make is 404ing.

However when i click into the URL it returns the JSON i need. The question i have is what could be causing this to 404?

Comment: You're making a POST request to it, yet it only responds to GET. If you need more specific help than that, please post your code in the question

Comment: I can only see a 200 when doing the petition yo said with the URL : https://ecuhelsinki.futurez.fi/wp-content/plugins/wp-plg-ct-vehicle-stats_1.0.5/includes/ctvc_ajax.php?r&ct_method=make

Comment: POST request works on other sites i have the plugin on and on postman. That url works fine, but it is 404ing on the first url i sent.